# Finding the first common number in multiple sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic-progressions

I wanna know if there is a formula/algorithm to get the first common number from multiple sequences.
For example:

S1 = 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, ...

S2 = 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, ...

S3 = 4, 8, 12, 16, ...

First common number is 12

If there is a way please let me know, because I've been looking for hours and can't find anything to solve this.

Comment: I doubt there's a method in general, but, here, you want the least common multiple (or lcm) of $2,3,4$. That's because $S_1$ is the multiples of $2$, $S_2$ those of $3$, and $S_3$ those of $4$. Thus if some number is in all three sequences, it is a multiple of all three - and the first such common member will be the *least* common multiple.

Comment: I guess this would work for my example, but doesn't really solve my problem.
I would need it to work for every Arithmetic Sequence
For example: 

S1 = 2, 4, 6, 8, ...

S2 = 2, 5, 8, 11, ...

S3 = 3, 8, 13, 18, ...

First common number is now 8

Comment: If you want a solution for *arithmetic sequences*, you should say so in the body of your question, not in a comment. And you should have a look at the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Comment: You need to mathematically identify each term in each sequence.  For example, S1 has #'s of the form $(2 + 2a)$, S2 has #'s of the form $(2 + 3b)$ and S3 has #'s of the form $(3 + 5c)$, where $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}.$  Such a formulation is always possible for a sequence of #'s in an arithmetic progression.  One approach is to identify the set $T$ of **all common elements** and then compute the minimum value in $T$.